# Changing file permissions for uploaded files with PHP

Tags: php, linux, file-permissions

To give you a little background I have created a website which allows users to upload images, which are subsequently re-sized and displayed. The website was working perfectly, but I recently moved it to a new server and have encountered a few issues.  I am nearly positive that the issue is the result of file permissions.  I have set my upload folder to 777, so all my previously uploaded files work without issue, but the problem arises when a new file is uploaded. When the file is uploaded, using SFTP access, the image has the permissions set to 666, the listed owner is apache. I wrote a few lines to experiment with the chmod function, but haven't hadn't any luck.

```
 <?php 
  require_once("/var/www/html/wp-load.php");
  echo shell_exec('whoami');
  $test = wp_getattachment_url(123);
  chmod($test, 0755);
  //chmod("/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/image.jpg", 0755);
  ?>
```

Outputted to the screen is apache, so the user is also the owner of the file, but changing the permissions has not been successful.

Comment: Why you need 755 permission on file itself. As owner (apache user) you already have read/write permission (666) on file even if you uploaded through sftp (As you say uploaded file owner is apache). Resize/display do not requires more permission.

Comment: That was actually just a test to see if I could alter the file permissions. I originally had the chmod command directly after I created the file. Perhaps permissions are not the cause of the problem.  Any other ideas as to why the resize function worked find on my previous server, but does not work on the new one? The uploaded file is saved as the full image, but the resized images are not created as they were previously.

Comment: If required resize libs like gd or imagemagic not enabled/installed on server.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I was in fact missing the gd library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If required resize libs like gd or imagemagic not enabled/installed on server.

NOTE : I added the My comments as answer, So question can be answered.